# Solr search query returning full head exception

Tags: c#-4.0, solr, jetty, solrnet

I am calling remote solr search hosted on other machine in a c# application. Now since my query length becomes too large so search engine is returning full head error. I can't reducing query length. so i just wanted to know can i make a post request for the same? how would i make this?Please suggest me.Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Looks like you are running into jetty's default GET parameter size limit.  This can be adjusted by changing headerBufferSize in jetty.xml.

Refer to this link on configuring jetty -
http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Configuring+Connectors

Comment: This seems to be deprecated now. You can use `<Set name="requestHeaderSize">65535</Set>` (64k) in the connector section of `etc/jetty.xml`

Comment: How to do this on tomcat?

Comment: How to do this in bitnami as well?

Answer (score 1):

You may also need to increase the requestBufferSize (the size of the buffer for the whole request, including headers). The default is 8k.